# Ace Editor autocompletion on mobile device

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I use ace editor on my application and stuck with autocompletion on mobile devices. If im using html-mode for example, i get a closing html tag automatically whenever i finish an opening tag. But this only works on desktop browser and not on mobile devices. Maybe it has something to do with triggering any event with android keyboard input? Maybe there is any chance to trigger it by myself like using:
`editor.commands.byName.startAutocomplete.exec(editor);` to open the autocompletion menu with javascript. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This most likely depends on keyboard, some keyboards may send > as part of composition. On which keyboard do you see this issue?

Comment: @auser Default android on-screen keyboard, tested on a Google Pixel 5.